# Updating Database never works on first time, have to do it twice?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, sql-update, sql-insert

I'm trying to update/edit a database using a DataGridView that the user can edit/insert rows/delete rows. Everything appears to work up to clicking on the "Insert" or "Update" link cells. They always fail on the first click (its not giving a detailed error) and always works on the second click.

I can't see what is changing between being clicked once or twice.

**LOADING THE DATA INTO THE DATAGRIDVIEW:**

```
private void loadDB()
        {
            try
            {
                string connstring = string.Format("Server={0}; database={1}; UID={2}; password={3}",
                dbUtil.creds.server, dbUtil.creds.database, dbUtil.creds.username, dbUtil.creds.password);

                conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);

                // since we have multiple tables we cant load data on form load
                // so we cant open conn there either. do it here, only once, the first time.
                onlyOnce();

                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT *, 'Delete' AS 'Delete' FROM RIS" + tableShown, conn);
                builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

                adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
                adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
                adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();

                ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds, "RIS" + tableShown);
                dbView.DataSource = null;
                dbView.DataSource = ds.Tables["RIS" + tableShown];

                for (int i = 0; i < dbView.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataGridViewLinkCell linkCell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
                    dbView[dbView.Columns.Count - 1, i] = linkCell;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            cellCount = dbView.Columns.Count - 1;
        }
```

**UPDATE CELL IF USER ADDED ROW:**

```
        private void dbView_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            int lastRow = dbView.Rows.Count - 2;
            DataGridViewRow nRow = dbView.Rows[lastRow];
            DataGridViewLinkCell linkCell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
            dbView[cellCount, lastRow] = linkCell;
            nRow.Cells["Delete"].Value = "Insert";
        }
```

**UPDATE CELL IF USER CHANGED A CELL IN EXISITING ROW:**

```
        private void dbView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int lastRow = e.RowIndex;
                DataGridViewRow nRow = dbView.Rows[lastRow];
                DataGridViewLinkCell linkCell = new DataGridViewLinkCell();
                dbView[cellCount, lastRow] = linkCell;
                if (dbView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[cellCount].Value.ToString() == "Delete")
                {
                    nRow.Cells["Delete"].Value = "Update";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        }
```

**DEPENDING ON CELL VALUE, UPDATE / INSERT / OR DELETE ROW:**

```
 private void dbView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            string database = "RIS" + tableShown;
            int result = 0;
            try
            {
                if (e.ColumnIndex == cellCount)
                {
                    string Task = dbView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[cellCount].Value.ToString();
                    if (Task == "Delete")
                    {
                        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete?", "Deleting...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            int ThisRow = e.RowIndex;
                            dbView.Rows.RemoveAt(ThisRow);
                            ds.Tables[database].Rows[ThisRow].Delete();
                            result = adapter.Update(ds, database);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (Task == "Insert")
                    {
                        int lastRow = dbView.Rows.Count - 2;
                        DataRow dr = ds.Tables[database].NewRow();
                        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dbView.Columns)
                        {
                            if (col.HeaderText != "Delete")
                            {
                                dr[col.HeaderText] = dbView.Rows[lastRow].Cells[col.HeaderText].Value;
                            }
                        }
                        ds.Tables[database].Rows.Add(dr);
                        ds.Tables[database].Rows.RemoveAt(ds.Tables[database].Rows.Count - 1);
                        dbView.Rows.RemoveAt(dbView.Rows.Count - 2);
                        dbView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[cellCount].Value = "Delete";
                        result = adapter.Update(ds, database);
                    }
                    else if (Task == "Update")
                    {
                        int thisRow = e.RowIndex;
                        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dbView.Columns)
                        {
                            if (col.HeaderText != "Delete")
                            {
                                ds.Tables[database].Rows[thisRow][col.HeaderText] = dbView.Rows[thisRow].Cells[col.HeaderText].Value;
                            }
                        }
                        result = adapter.Update(ds, database);
                        dbView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[cellCount].Value = "Delete";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
            // reload data to clear ds and dt after success
            if(result > 0)
            {
                loadDB();
            }
        }
```

Any ideas why the linkcell fails first time its clicked but not the second time?

Comment: what do you mean by fails at the first time? Is there any exception?

Comment: Managed to get a more detailed exception: [unable to write data to the transport connection. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.]

Comment: Have tried setting POOLING to false and true, neither make a difference.

Comment: I've got no idea why you're bothering with ANY of this. A datatable already tracks changes made to its rows in add/update/delete fashion. You're needlessly reinventing a wheel here

Comment: No, the Dataset tracks changes, which then have to be updated to the remote MySql server. Which is what this does...

Comment: LoadDB is run AFTER the initial event. Which means your connection.open() method call hasn't been executed until AFTER you attempted the insert/update. 

my assumption is your are using a variable on the form somehwhere, that is seperate from the first load, so your db_ViewCellContentClick method, doesn't have the connection opened. 

try adding "onlyOnce();"
as the first line in that method.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may come across this with a similar error, here's a more elegant way of doing it (with no errors).

```
        private void loadDB()
        {
            
                string connstring = string.Format("Server={0}; database={1}; UID={2}; password={3};",
                dbUtil.creds.server, dbUtil.creds.database, dbUtil.creds.username, dbUtil.creds.password);

                conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);

            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from RIS" + tableShown, conn);
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(DS);
                dbView.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                //When handling errors, you can your application's response based on the error number.
                //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
                //0: Cannot connect to server.
                //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server. Contact administrator");
                        break;
                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        break;
                    default:
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void dbView_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable changes = ((DataTable)dbView.DataSource).GetChanges();

            if (changes != null)
            {
                MySqlCommandBuilder mcb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                adapter.UpdateCommand = mcb.GetUpdateCommand();
                adapter.Update(changes);
                ((DataTable)dbView.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
            }
        }
```